# Estimating point of flat behavior of curve?

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-data, linear

I am working with discrete data that falls along a decay-like curve, and I want to estimate a $k$ such that for $i > k$, the y value doesn't change much at all.

Here's simulated data that looks similar to the type of data I'm working with:

```
x <- sample(1:15, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
y <- ifelse(x <= 4, exp(-.5*x), exp(-.5*4)) + rnorm(n = 500, mean = 0, sd = .02)
d <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
```

The data looks like this:

[image: basic problem set up]

The answer that I'm looking for here is **4** (that's the point at which the function becomes constant). Obviously in the real data I don't know the underlying generative distribution.

My thought process is the follows:

```
summary(lm(y ~ I(x >= 1) + I(x >= 2) + I(x >= 3) + I(x >= 4) + 
               I(x >= 5) + I(x >= 6) + I(x >= 7) + I(x >= 8) + 
               I(x >= 9) + I(x >= 10) + I(x >= 11) + I(x >= 12) + 
               I(x >= 13) + I(x >= 14) + I(x >= 15), data = d))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ I(x >= 1) + I(x >= 2) + I(x >= 3) + I(x >= 4) + 
    I(x >= 5) + I(x >= 6) + I(x >= 7) + I(x >= 8) + I(x >= 9) + 
    I(x >= 10) + I(x >= 11) + I(x >= 12) + I(x >= 13) + I(x >= 
    14) + I(x >= 15), data = d)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.05524 -0.01214 -0.00069  0.01349  0.06000 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     0.6076665  0.0047280 128.525   <2e-16 ***
I(x >= 1)TRUE          NA         NA      NA       NA    
I(x >= 2)TRUE  -0.2419432  0.0057645 -41.971   <2e-16 ***
I(x >= 3)TRUE  -0.1447856  0.0048424 -29.899   <2e-16 ***
I(x >= 4)TRUE  -0.0857928  0.0056334 -15.229   <2e-16 ***
I(x >= 5)TRUE   0.0118514  0.0063512   1.866   0.0626 .  
I(x >= 6)TRUE  -0.0102245  0.0057456  -1.780   0.0758 .  
I(x >= 7)TRUE  -0.0019854  0.0052848  -0.376   0.7073    
I(x >= 8)TRUE  -0.0003242  0.0066960  -0.048   0.9614    
I(x >= 9)TRUE   0.0043633  0.0065281   0.668   0.5042    
I(x >= 10)TRUE -0.0001374  0.0057477  -0.024   0.9809    
I(x >= 11)TRUE -0.0049601  0.0056334  -0.880   0.3790    
I(x >= 12)TRUE  0.0049031  0.0054166   0.905   0.3658    
I(x >= 13)TRUE -0.0029552  0.0054166  -0.546   0.5856    
I(x >= 14)TRUE -0.0017904  0.0052962  -0.338   0.7355    
I(x >= 15)TRUE -0.0005321  0.0042936  -0.124   0.9014    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02006 on 485 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9653,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9643 
F-statistic: 963.1 on 14 and 485 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So, I create dummy variables that don't just encode the x value, but encode >= the x value, the idea being that any additional value would have to add information beyond all of the previous values for it to be useful in the model. Had I just encoded the x value as discrete factors and done the dummy encoding the normal way, all of the x values would have been significant, since they are all independently informative *compared to the baseline*.

You can see that by looking at the p-values, it recovers "4" as the answer (it's the last value for which the result is very significant).

My question is: is this a valid way of thinking about this problem? Also, somewhat less importantly, is there a more succinct way of coding this in R without all of the `I(x >= i)`s?

Comment: I suggest adding the tag "R" to this question.

Comment: Would this be helpful: fitting two straight lines to x and y, then finding the intersection of those two lines where their value is equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the segmented package:

```
library(segmented)
fit <- segmented(lm(y ~ x, data = d), seg.Z = ~ x)
summary(fit)

#estimated breakpoint:
confint(fit)
#$`x`
#    Est. CI(95%).l CI(95%).u
# 3.37186   3.32887   3.41485

plot(y ~ x, data = d)
curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = x)), add = TRUE)
```

[image: resulting graph]

One could consider fitting the model to a transformed DV to account for slight curvature left of the breakpoint but it doesn't seem necessary for this specific example.